# How do I add configuration option to a module?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm configuring a DotNetNuke v7+ portal and wish to add a module that will be configurable by editors. The editor should be shown a configuration panel with a single text control and an update button.

The value of this control will be passed to the public web view within a piece of javascript code, similar to passing a tracking ID to Google Analytic Script.

I've looked at the Google Analytics module and understand how to handle the text control and update, but the innards are all wrapped up inside a DLL so I can't work out how to handle the public facing display.

Can this all be done within a single module, or do I also need to create a settings.aspx file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately Dnn is open source, so it's just a matter of finding the right file to see the example. In this case, check out here

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/tree/012dcf82ea23ebfa2f8484f369b0d15f3c5f7590/Website/DesktopModules/Admin/Analytics

You don't need a separate control for this. You can do it within a settings control.

If you're new to Dnn Module Development, I strongly recommend checking out [Christoc's Templates](http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/). They have examples and patterns for common Dnn module requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lucas. The files you've linked to are the ones I was originaly using to base my new module on. Since posting the question I have also found the JS in a SiteAnalytics.config along with what I gather are variables to replace.

I'm still unsure how it is displayed on the site but I'm a lot closer to fathoming it out. I'll check out Christoc's examples.

Comment: @MikeRidyard in the Christoc example, check out the Settings.ascx(.cs) files.
http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/Settings.ascx.cs